# flask-sqlalchemy doing math in admin model

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, flask-admin

I'm just new to flask-sqlalchemy and flask-admin. I want to do the simple calculation  and it works if I use just a  python shell but when I try to do x+y via flask admin a get an error:

> TypeError: **init**() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'x' and 'y'

The purpose is automatically to receive the sum of x+y in **z** column when I put 'x' and 'y' in admin form Math.

Here is my piece of code:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class Math(db.Model):

     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     x = db.Column(db.Integer)
     y = db.Column(db.Integer)
     z = db.Column(db.Integer)

     def __init__(self, x, y):
         self.x = x
         self.y = y
         self.z = self.x+self.y

admin = Admin(app, name='Test', template_mode='bootstrap3')
admin.add_view(ModelView(Math, db.session))


db.drop_all()
db.create_all()

if __name__=='__main__':
   app.run(debug=True)
```

Please help me to understand what I'm doing wrong and how it can be fixed. Many thank in advance

Answer (score 0):

In order to work with flask-admin views your models must have `__init__` method with default signature (only `self` argument) because it is called by flask-admin view in such way:

```py
model = self.model()
```

I think you are trying to implement logic which automatically fills `z` column on changing `x` and `y` columns. You can accomplish this by using [hybrid attributes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html):

```py
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property

class Math(db.model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    x = db.Column(db.Integer)
    y = db.Column(db.Integer)

    @hybrid_property
    def z(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

`z` is a virtual column here which does not exist in `math` table but is calculated on the fly.